# No puedo conectarme a la base de datos (LARAVEL 8)

Tags: php, laravel, odbc, sybase, sqlsrv

quisiera ver si pueden ayudarme en un problemita que tengo :C.
En mi trabajo usan una base de datos a la que llaman ORDEN. A esta solo se pueden conectar los que estén conectados con el cable de red en la pega.
El sistema actual está hecho en vb.net y se conecta a la ORDEN sin problemas. El problema está en que este sistema quieren llevarlo a laravel y no sé como conectarme a esta red desde ahí(ORDEN).
Adjuntaré dos fotos. La primera es como la gente de soporte habilitó la conexión de mi computador a la ORDEN(lo hacen a través de odbc). La segunda es lo que yo intenté hacer para acceder a la red, pero de igual forma no resultó (Si lo desean puedo mostrarles como se hizo la conexión a la orden a través de vb.net).
No logro comprender si el driver que tengo que usar es odbc, sqlsrv o directamente tengo que buscar uno para ASE sybase. Por favor, agradecería mucho la ayuda. Además, tampoco he podido entender cuales son los campos que tengo que poner para cada configuracion de driver(intenté un par de veces con los primeros 2).
PD: Adjunté una tercera foto. Este es el error que me daba al ejecutar la conexión de sqlsrv(segunda foto).
Muchas gracias por su tiempo y perdonen el mucho texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y ya evaluaste cada una de las opciones que pueden estar generando ese error como te indica el mensaje de error?

Comment: @BetaM La verdad soy nuevo en esto de conectarme con bases de datos y todo lo que tenga que ver con esto, por lo que me cuesta entender que es lo quiere decir el mensaje:  1. sqlsrv lo tengo bien instalado, una persona me ayudó a ver eso. ¿Con tenerlo bien instalado ya puedo descartar este punto?           2. Como digo en la publicación, tengo un programa en el mismo computador que está programado en vb.net. Este también se conecta a la ORDEN y funciona. ¿Con eso no podría descartar los posibles problemas 2 y 3?

Comment: ¿o acaso es posible que me pueda conectar solo en un programa por computador?. Cabe mencionar que al momento de lanzar la aplicacion laravel, no tengo abierto el programa de vb.net

Comment: Si la aplicación de Vb.net se conecta con ODBC debieras usar ODBC. Imagino que tienes la extensión odbc de php instalada. Muéstranos por favor qué intentaste (con código, no con foto) y qué has investigado, para no empezar de cero si puedo echar una mano